# Multiple Authors for list element

Tags: list, co-authoring

I have created a Canvas App connected to a SharePoint list. I need the setting to be as follows:

- Users should all be able to create new items
- Users are, per default, only allowed to see their own elements
- BUT users should be able to share single elements with other users.

For current setting see pictures.

I have tried:

1. Sharing the element. When the user receiving the link tries to open it they receive a error (see picture) saying the element is deleted/not available.
2. creating a flow that changes the author, but when the author is changed, only the new author sees the element (no longer visible to first author)

I appreciate all ideas.

List settings:

[image: List settings]

User permissions:

[image: User permissions]

Error message:

[image: Error message]

Comment: Please take a look at this documentation: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-permissions-for-a-sharepoint-list-or-library-02d770f3-59eb-4910-a608-5f84cc297782